# R corrplot - color relying on value

Tags: r, plot, r-corrplot

I have a binary `data.fram`e (53115 rows; 520 columns) and I want to plot a correlation plot. I want to colour it based on the values, correlation values >=0.95 (red), otherwise, blue.

```
correl <- abs(round(cor(bin_mat), 2))

pdf("corrplot.pdf", width = 200, height = 200)
a <- corrplot(correl, order = "hclust", addCoef.col = "black", number.cex=0.8, cl.lim = c(0,1), col=c(rep("deepskyblue",19) ,"red"))
dev.off()
```

I get the correlation plot but in many cases I get a wrong coloring (see below on 0.91).

[image: picture]

data: [file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/1kfnl5t0a5fodko/dataset.csv/file)

How can I manage to have a right coloring?

Answer (score 1):

In general `corrplot` library is quite weird when it comes to `cl.lim` and colors. For some reason it doesn't seem to matter if you set `cl.lim` or not - the colors will still be distributed from -1 to 1.

So in your case just use 39 blue colors instead of 19 (to cover the range from -1 to 1):

```
cors <- cor(iris[,-5])
cors[cbind(c(1,2), c(2,1))] <- 0.912
corrplot(cors, col=c(rep("blue", 39), "red"), cl.lim=c(-1,1), addCoef.col="black")
```

And the result:
[image: corrplot]